# Detect html lang with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, multilingual, lang

I'm using a multilingual plugin in Wordpress that enables users to change their language options on a website.

This plugin among other things changes the HTML language attribute e.g.

```
<html lang="en-GB">
```

or

```
<html lang="en-US">
```

I've tried to detect the language using the following selector:

```
if ($( 'html:lang(en-us)')) {
    alert('US lang detected');
}
```

However this creates a false positive as other elements further down the page are set to 'en-us' even if the opening HTML attribute is set to 'en-GB'.

What selector would specifically examine only the opening HTML attribute?

Comment: Use `$('html[lang="en-us"]')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using jQuery for a task like this, you may be making things unnecessarily complicated and slow:

```js
if ( document.documentElement.lang.toLowerCase() === "en-us" ) {
    alert( "American English." );
}
```

Vanilla JavaScript is better for menial tasks like reading an attribute value, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the feedback. The Javascripts handling the job perfectly.

Answer (score 7):

Your selector is correct, but you're using it in the if statement incorrectly.

`$( 'html:lang(en-us)')` will return a jQuery object. jQuery objects are *always* truthy, so your if statement will always evaluate to true.

A simple fix is to use the [`.is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) function, which will return a boolean:

```
if ($('html').is(':lang(en-us)')) {
    alert('US lang detected');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining things, it's much appreciated. Went with a plain Javascript solution as advised by another comment, however this would have also done the job.

Answer (score 2):

You have to check for `length`:

```js
if ( $("html:lang(en-us)").length > 0 ) {
    alert( 'US lang detected' );
}
```

Comment: Since positive numbers are *truthy* in JavaScript, you could remove the `>0` portion of the conditional statement, and the code would be equally valid. (just be careful with negative numbers)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('html[lang="en-us"]')
```

should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the lang as attr, like the code in snippet

```js
console.log($("html").attr("lang"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is working for me  in WordPress

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ console.log("cons"); if ( $("html:lang(en)").length > 0 ) {
   alert( 'US lang detected' );
} });
```